# Solved: Incomplete baking of a lighting situation with environment to the map

Tags: baking

I'm trying to bake a relatively simple situation(with cycles, of course).
I'm getting weird combinations on some faces and incomplete renders on others, some are completely mid-grey without any shading. As you can see, a large area below the object (lower left) is rendered correctly.
What I made sure of:
– UV maps are laid out with some island margins
– They don't overlap
– The render in the viewport by Cycles on the right shows expected lighting

Any Ideas?
[image: Screenshot of the UV page]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: So, what I finally found out: We used a lot of Boolean operations to build the architecture. As you may have experienced too, that may leave some very small gaps between neighbouring faces. Sometimes you notice these only when checking your results after the bake. BUT, when you try to fix these locally, your UV maps may change places massively! So, always do a fresh UV mapping after any such corrections, as small as they may seem.